# Should I call a function from HTML or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Which is better?

```
<form action="javascript:myFunction()">
```

or

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function(){ /* etc. */ });
```

Is one way better than the other or is it just personal preference?

Comment: ***Always*** attach your events in JS code. Using `javascript:*` or `on*` attributes is considered bad practice and very outdated.

Comment: I marked it as dupe because i guess it would help you more

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Okay, so it is a thing! But why is it considered bad practice and outdated?

Comment: The marked dupe is marked as dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice  :)

Comment: @A.Wolff Okay, much better! That first dupe had no actual information in it! I still don't understand what is bad about the original way. I'm looking out for an underlying problem to avoid in general. Is it just a separation of the languages thing?

Comment: Mostly, yes, which is vital when working in a team and saves a lot of time when maintaining/modifying the code at a later date.